# Setup Jenkins on Kubernetes - Error 403

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins

I am on a IaaS Kubernetes k8s on a Virtual Machine.

I have setup a nginx and some other apps which are working well. (I can reach my apps)

I am using nginx ingress controller.

When I try to reach jenkins outside of the node, I get an empty reply but the ingress logs show a 403

When I curl jenkins inside of the node I can reach it without any problem

When I restart the Jenkins container, I can access the `Please wait while Jenkins is getting ready to work ...` page but after it is ready, I get a 403 again.

Any idea why this is happening?

Ingress ressource:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
  labels:
    project: cicd
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:status:
        f:loadBalancer:
          f:ingress: {}
    manager: nginx-ingress-controller
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-04-02T17:11:25Z"
  - apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:annotations:
          .: {}
          f:kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration: {}
          f:kubernetes.io/ingress.class: {}
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:project: {}
      f:spec:
        f:rules: {}
    manager: kubectl
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-04-02T17:12:56Z"
  name: jenkins
  namespace: jenkins
spec:
  rules:
  - host: jenkins.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: jenkins
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /
        pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

nginx.conf

```
## start server jenkins.com
    server {
        server_name jenkins.com ;

        listen 80  ;
        listen 443  ssl http2 ;

        set $proxy_upstream_name "-";

        ssl_certificate_by_lua_block {
            certificate.call()
        }

        location / {

            set $namespace      "jenkins";
            set $ingress_name   "jenkins";
            set $service_name   "jenkins";
            set $service_port   "8080";
            set $location_path  "/";

            rewrite_by_lua_block {
                lua_ingress.rewrite({
                    force_ssl_redirect = false,
                    ssl_redirect = true,
                    force_no_ssl_redirect = false,
                    use_port_in_redirects = false,
                })
                balancer.rewrite()
                plugins.run()
            }

            header_filter_by_lua_block {

                plugins.run()
            }
            body_filter_by_lua_block {

            }

            log_by_lua_block {

                balancer.log()

                monitor.call()

                plugins.run()
            }

            port_in_redirect off;

            set $balancer_ewma_score -1;
            set $proxy_upstream_name "jenkins-jenkins-8080";
            set $proxy_host          $proxy_upstream_name;
            set $pass_access_scheme  $scheme;
            set $pass_server_port    $server_port;
            set $best_http_host      $http_host;
            set $pass_port           $pass_server_port;

            set $proxy_alternative_upstream_name "";

            client_max_body_size                    10m;

            proxy_set_header Host                   $best_http_host;

            # Pass the extracted client certificate to the backend

            # Allow websocket connections
            proxy_set_header                        Upgrade           $http_upgrade;

            proxy_set_header                        Connection        $connection_upgrade;

            proxy_set_header X-Request-ID           $req_id;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-IP              $remote_addr;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For        $remote_addr;

            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host       $best_http_host;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Port       $pass_port;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto      $pass_access_scheme;

            proxy_set_header X-Scheme               $pass_access_scheme;

            # Pass the original X-Forwarded-For
            proxy_set_header X-Original-Forwarded-For $http_x_forwarded_for;

            # mitigate HTTPoxy Vulnerability
            # https://www.nginx.com/blog/mitigating-the-httpoxy-vulnerability-with-nginx/
            proxy_set_header Proxy                  "";

            # Custom headers to proxied server

            proxy_connect_timeout                   5s;
            proxy_send_timeout                      86400s;
            proxy_read_timeout                      86400s;

            proxy_buffering                         off;
            proxy_buffer_size                       4k;
            proxy_buffers                           4 4k;

            proxy_max_temp_file_size                1024m;

            proxy_request_buffering                 on;
            proxy_http_version                      1.1;

            proxy_cookie_domain                     off;
            proxy_cookie_path                       off;

            # In case of errors try the next upstream server before returning an error
            proxy_next_upstream                     error timeout;
            proxy_next_upstream_timeout             0;
            proxy_next_upstream_tries               3;

            proxy_pass http://upstream_balancer;

            proxy_redirect                          off;

        }

    }
```

curl -v command

```
* Connected to jenkins.com (xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.29.0
> Host: jenkins.com
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
< Server: openresty/1.15.8.2
< Date: Sun, 05 Apr 2020 18:09:23 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 793
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID.fe94dd2e=node01swwo52ouan0zf0m57265cwjo109.node0; Path=/; HttpOnly
< Expires: Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 GMT
< X-Hudson: 1.395
< X-Jenkins: 2.222.1
< X-Jenkins-Session: efb06340
< X-Hudson-CLI-Port: 50000
< X-Jenkins-CLI-Port: 50000
< X-Jenkins-CLI2-Port: 50000
< X-You-Are-Authenticated-As: anonymous
< X-You-Are-In-Group-Disabled: JENKINS-39402: use -Dhudson.security.AccessDeniedException2.REPORT_GROUP_HEADERS=true or use /whoAmI to diagnose
< X-Required-Permission: hudson.model.Hudson.Read
< X-Permission-Implied-By: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
< X-Permission-Implied-By: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
< 
<html><head><meta http-equiv='refresh' content='1;url=/login?from=%2F'/><script>window.location.replace('/login?from=%2F');</script></head><body style='background-color:white; color:white;'>


Authentication required
<!--
You are authenticated as: anonymous
Groups that you are in:

Permission you need to have (but didn't): hudson.model.Hudson.Read
 ... which is implied by: hudson.security.Permission.GenericRead
 ... which is implied by: hudson.model.Hudson.Administer
```

I am editing /etc/hosts in order to point jenkins.com to my node (On the machine trying to access jenkins and getting 403)

Comment: Could you include your Ingress object here and update the question?

Comment: Sorry about that, It has been added

Comment: Hi Sartigan, welcome to S.F.; please post the actual `curl -v` experiences for both the good and bad outcomes, because we can't _guess_ what's wrong with your setup

Comment: Sorry again about that, it has been added

Comment: @Sartigan Have you maybe tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51660328/11560878)?

Comment: It is not so easy to get jekins to run well within Kubernetes. I would consider Tekton in kubernetes instead. https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline

Answer (score 2):

This is a community wiki answer.

There are three most common solutions for this issue:

1. If you don't mind reducing security of your Jenkins installation, you can uncheck "Prevent Cross Site Request Forgery exploits" in jenkins.com/configureSecurity section [image]

   2. A safer one: "Enable proxy compatibility" in the "Configure Global Security" options [image]
   3. If you access problem is due to crumb token issue, you can follow [this short guide](https://linuxacademy.com/community/show/28964-no-valid-crumb-was-included-in-the-request/) to resolve it.

Please let me know if that helped.